# Question on Python super multiple inheritance

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, super

I am new to Python, and I am really confused about the super function and multiple inheritance.

Here is the toy Code:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class A')        
        print('Leave class A')

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class C')
        A.__init__(self)
        print('Leave class C')
class D(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class D')
        #A.__init__(self)
        super(D,self).__init__()
        print('Leave class D')
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class B')
        super(B,self).__init__()
        print('Leave class B')

class E(C,B,D):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class E')
        B.__init__(self)
        #C.__init__(self)
        #D.__init__(self)
        print('Leave class E')
```

Then the output is:

```
Call class E
Call class B
Call class D
Call class A
Leave class A
Leave class D
Leave class B
Leave class E
(<class '__main__.E'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

where `__init__` of Class D is called. However, if I change class E to:

```
class E(B,C,D):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class E')
        B.__init__(self)
        #C.__init__(self)
        #D.__init__(self)
        print('Leave class E')
```

where the order of B,C,D is changed, then the output is:

```
Call class E
Call class B
Call class C
Call class A
Leave class A
Leave class C
Leave class B
Leave class E
(<class '__main__.E'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

then the `__init__` of class D will not be called, but class C's, although class does not use `super` function.

Does someone know:
1. In the first code, why `__init__` of class D is also called?
2. In the second code, why `__init__` of class C is called and `__init__` of class D is not?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PyTorch, this is a pure Python problem. The problem is calling __init__ of a class with another class instance as argument, this makes no sense and is the cause of the weird behaviours.

Comment: You have to use `super` consistently within the hierarchy (that's why we say `super` supports *cooperative* inheritance).

Comment: Watch this talk to learn all about inheritance and super(): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Comment: @Dese no, that's pretty normal in Python, and it makes perfect sense. Indeed, it's what you would *have* to do before `super` was available, and it's totally fine if you aren't trying to use cooperative *multiple* inheritance.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Indeed I should have been more explicit: do not do it if you also use super

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Failing to use `super` consistently means you aren't guaranteeing that the MRO will be walked properly.

In your first example, the explicit call to `B.__init__` in `E.__init__` ensures that `C.__init__` never gets called, because `B` comes after `C` in the MRO.

In the second example, `B` just happens to be the next class after `E`, so nothing broke (yet). But then in `C.__init__`, you again use `A.__init__(self)` instead of `super(C, self).__init__()`, which means you jumped straight from `C` to `A`, bypassing `D` which should have come next.

When designing a class *hierarchy* that uses `super` (not just a single class), you have to ensure that *every* class uses `super` to ensure that the MRO selected by the *runtime* type of `self` is followed, rather than hard-coding calls to parent class methods at *compile*-time.

The correct definition would be

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class A')
        super().__init__()       
        print('Leave class A')

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class C')
        super().__init__()
        print('Leave class C')
class D(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class D')
        super().__init__()
        print('Leave class D')
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class B')
        super().__init__()
        print('Leave class B')

class E(C,B,D):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Call class E')
        super().__init__(self)
        print('Leave class E')
```

In Python 3, some compiler magic provides the "default" arguments when `super` is called without any. For example, in `E.__init__`, `super().__init___()` is equivalent to `super(C, self).__init__()`.

Because the value of `self` (and thus its type) is constant throughout the chain of calls, each use of `super()` refers to the next class in the MRO for `type(self)`. In the above example, that would thus produce the output

```
Call class E
Call class C
Call class B
Call class D
Call class A
Leave class A
Leave class D
Leave class B
Leave class C
Leave class E
```

If you change the order of base classes in the definition of `E`, the MRO (and thus the output) will update automatically without having to change any further code.